# Similar code. One works, one crashes. Why?

Tags: c++

I was working on a problem for Project Euler using C++ in Code::Blocks 10.05 and found my program to be crashing in a strange place: the initialization.  Here is a code snippet that reproduces the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

vector<deque<uint32_t> > f;

int main()
{
    deque<uint32_t> p;
    deque<uint32_t>::iterator dit1,dit2;
    p.push_back(0);
    p.push_back(1);
    f.push_back(p);
    cout << f.back().size() << endl;
    cout << "f= ";
    for(dit1==f.back().begin();dit1!=f.back().end();dit1++) cout << *dit1 << " ";
    cout << "Checkpoint" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Before posting here, I tried a test program to see if I could figure out the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
    uint64_t i;
    deque<uint32_t> d;
    vector<deque<uint32_t> > vd;
    deque<uint32_t>::iterator it;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) d.push_back(i);
    vd.push_back(d);
    for(it=vd.back().begin();it!=vd.back().end();it++) cout << *it << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

The first program crashes while the second correctly reproduces the deque.  Besides variable names, the only major difference I see is the first program uses a global variable and the test program uses a local variable.  So why does the first program crash in the for loop while the second does not?

Comment: `dit1` is uninitialized in the 1st example (`dit1==f.back().begin()` is not an assignment). Hence, dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have no idea what this means.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Good catch.  If you had had this as an answer rather than a comment, I'd have accepted it.

Comment: @Mike Simple, read the link so you understand it, 
Your problem is caused by a typo, and that is off-topic in SO. The task of debugging is fundamental for a good programmer

Comment: @eyllanesc I wrote an entire test program in an attempt to debug it.  And why do you think I'm printing out the list in the first place?  I know what should be in there.  Another attempt to debug. And how I found the source of the crash.  I simply didn't spot an extra "=".

Comment: @Mike 
You must learn to use professional debugging tools such as GDB, if you had read the link you would have understood, these types of questions are off-topic because they will not help future readers. read [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm new to this site (came from Mathematics) and not a professional programmer.  I wouldn't know how to use watches to monitor a complex datatype such as a vector of deques.  It's often much easier to use "cout"s to debug.  For example, how do I know the crash was in the for loop?  Because "Checkpoint" never printed.  And I do think I created a "minimal, complete, and verifiable example".  I assure you I read that before posting here.  I admit, the title kind of stinks, but given that I didn't know the source of the crash, I couldn't think of a better name.

Comment: @Mike 
Do not make excuses of a professional nature, in SO programming questions are asked, you understand programmers. I have another profession but I know that by getting into this world I must learn to use tools. So we will assume that you are a programmer even if you do not believe it, we can not discriminate. Simple, review the site, review other questions, review the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `==` instead of `=` in the for loop in the first program.

Comment: Oops.  Can't believe I missed that.  That will do it.  Thanks.  I will accept the answer once I am able.